# What is the best approach to mute/unmute sound in list of videos

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, notifydatasetchanged

I am showing the list of videos using `TextureView` and `MediaPlayer`. I want to mute/unmute sound for all videos.

**What is the problem**

Problem is that when I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method then the playing video gets reloaded because `onBindViewHolder()` executes after `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**Code on mute/unmute icon's click**

```
case R.id.volume_button:
                if (isToPlaySoundInitially) {
                    volumeKey.setImageResource(R.drawable.unmute_video);
                    isToPlaySoundInitially = false;
                    mVideoView.unMuteVideo();

                } else {
                    volumeKey.setImageResource(R.drawable.mute_video);
                    isToPlaySoundInitially = true;
                    mVideoView.muteVideo();

                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
```

**Method to mute/unmute sound**

```
public void muteVideo() {
    if (this.mp != null) {
        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
    }
}

public void unMuteVideo() {
    if (this.mp != null) {
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Please suggest how can I mute/unmute sound for all items of the list.

Thank You.

Comment: Can u post some of your code?

Comment: I have updated my question with code of click event in Adapter

Comment: I hope you create holder for your item, from that you can directly touch your item view.

Comment: Yes, but I have to mute for all items on click of any one item. Like in Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Use setVolume function of MediaPlayer class to set the volume to 0. 
Do not use AudioManager class, because using AudioManager if you set volume to 0, then it set volume to 0 for all the instance of MediaPlayer and VideoView.

But if you will use setVolume() method of MediaPlayer then it will just Mute the volume of that instance only.

Also set volume to 0 is not easy using VideoView because VideoView is a wrapper over MediaPlayer class and just allow to access few function of MediaPlayer.

Comment: I think this is not my problem. I don't have any issue to mute and unmute particular video.  I want to mute sound for all videos when I mute any one video, same for unmute. You can check Facebook application if you have any doubt.

Comment: i hope this might help you :http://stackoverflow.com/a/10896086/7795876